# Symfony4 DateTimeType show invalid date

Tags: symfony, datetime

I do not understand why creating a DayTimePicker control via Symfony Forms:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('start', DateType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
            ),
            'data' => new DateTime('last day of previous month')
        ))

        ->add('end', DateType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
            ),
            'data' => new \DateTime("now")
        ))

        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('attr' => array('label' => 'Generate'))
    ;
}
```

Receives a choice date 31 April 2018 Because choosing this date and sending the form this date does not pass even validation so why is it generated?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell DateTime how to format your date. Try with :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('start', DateType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
            ),
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'data' => new DateTime('last day of previous month')->format('Y-m-d')
        ))

        ->add('end', DateType::class, array(
            'attr' => array(
            ),
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'data' => new \DateTime("now")->format('Y-m-d')
        ))

        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('attr' => array('label' => 'Generate'))
    ;
}
```